# How to create a link to a lotus notes group email box

Tags: lotus-notes

I know how to get the link to a bookmarked application/email inbox but I was wondering if there was a way of getting this link without adding my own account into the access list for a mail box  and adding it into my lotus. Just so it's easier than having to manually add them for users (we have loads, for individual clients so why I have added and removed myself for our main company wide in boxes. I'd love to be able to get the links easily for each .)

I have access to add/remove people from the email inboxes but that's as far as my admin access goes.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve? What do you need the database link for?

Answer (score 0):

Why are you adding yourself to the access control list?  Presumably if you are an admin, you'd have admin access in the acl by being part of some admin group already in the acl. You can send a doclink to the end users by adding the database to your workspace, right clicking and choosing database-->copy as link, then pasting that link into an email.